# Change Facebook login locale

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android app which uses Facebook login using facebook SDK. when I login, the default language is not English. Can anyone help me how to change app locale for login without having to update Facebook SDK code, as I am using facebook sdk's aar file.

Comment: have you found any solution for this?